# Click в canvas по нескольким элементам

Tags: javascript, canvas, click

Хочу сделать кликабельными картинки-'спутники', вращающиеся вокруг десяти 'планет'. У всех 'планет' разное кол-во 'спутников'(из массива images)..)

Фрагмент кода:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var W = window.innerWidth,
  H = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

var angle = 0;

var currentAngle = 0;
var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;
var particles = [];
var Lradius = 20;
var radius = 80;
var images = [
  ['img/1', 'img/2', 'img/3', 'img/4', 'img/5'],
  ['img/6', 'img/7'],
  ['img/8', 'img/9', 'img/10', 'img/11'],
  ['img/12', 'img/13', 'img/14', 'img/15'],
  ['img/16', 'img/17', 'img/18'],
  ['img/19', 'img/20', 'img/21'],
  ['img/22', 'img/23', 'img/24'],
  ['img/26', 'img/25'],
  ['img/27', 'img/28'],
  ['img/29', 'img/31', 'img/32']
];

function Particle() {
  this.images = images[i];
  this.radius = 20;
  this.radis = 80;
  this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width / 2) +
    this.radius * 1.5);
  this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.height / 2) +
    this.radius * 1.5);

  this.speedx = Math.round((Math.random() * 101) + 0) / 100;
  this.speedy = Math.round((Math.random() * 101) + 0) / 100;

  this.move = function() {


    context.beginPath();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    //картинка - 'планета'
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x, this.y);
    context.rotate(Gangle * TO_RADIANS);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'img/bag.png';
    context.drawImage(image, 20, -20, 40, 40);
    context.restore();
    angle += 0.1;

    for (var m = 0; m < this.images.length; m++) {
      //картинки - "спутники" на каждую планету
      var satellit = new Image();
      satellit.src = this.images[m];
      var vx = Math.cos(m + currentAngle) * this.radius;
      var vy = Math.sin(m + currentAngle) * this.radius;
      this.Ax = (this.x - this.Lradius) + vx;
      this.Ay = (this.y - this.Lradius) + vy;
      context.drawImage(image2, this.Ax, this.Ay, 20, 20);

    }
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var particle = new Particle();
  particles.push(particle);
}

function animate() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].move();

  }
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
}
animate();

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  // так получается кликнуть только по одному 'спутнику' каждой 'планеты', если их создавать совсем отдельными объектами - орбиты 'планет' и 'спутников' не совпадают..
  // Как сохранить сопряжение орбит и правильно перебрать 'спутники' каждой 'планеты'?


  var xCoord = e.offsetX;
  var yCoord = e.offsetY;
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    if ((xCoord >= particles[i].Ax - particles[i].Lradius && xCoord <= particles[i].Ax + particles[i].Lradius) && (yCoord >= particles[i].Ay - particles[i].Lradius && yCoord <= particles[i].Ay + particles[i].Lradius)) {

      alert('click');

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Сделайте. В чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема описана.

Comment: Непонятно. Попробуйте переформулировать проблему. И описать её более подробно

Comment: Кликабелен один "спутник"  каждой "планеты", ("планет" 10, "спутников" у каждой от 2 до 5), не могу разобраться, как сохраняя привязанность "спутников" к "своим " "планетам" сделать их кликабельными (кликнуть по "планетам" просто, а по "спутникам" не выходит, пробовал прямо в конструкторе запушить их в отдельный массив и обработать его - не получилось..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил сделать так:

```js
/**
 * Спутник
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {Planet} planet
 * @constructor
 */
function Satellite(data, planet) {
  this.planet = planet;
  this.x = data.x;
  this.y = data.y;

  this.move = function move() {
    /* реализация движения спутника */

    // при этом здесь доступны данные планеты
    this.planet.x;
    this.planet.y;
  }
}

/**
 * Планета
 * @param {Object} data
 * @constructor
 */
function Planet(data) {
  this.radius = data.radius;
  this.satellites = [];
  this.x = data.x;
  this.y = data.y;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.satellites.length; i++) {
    this.satellites.push(new Satellite(data.satellites[i], this));
  }

  this.move = function move() {
    /* реализация движения только планеты */

    // и запуск движения спутников
    for (var i = 0; i < this.satellites.length; i++) {
      this.satellites[i].move();
    }
  }
}

// данные о планетах
var data = [{
  name: 'Earth',
  radius: 80,
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  satellites: [{
    name: 'Moon',
    radius: 10,
    x: 20, // относительно земли
    y: 20
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Mars',
  radius: 40,
  x: 160,
  y: 180,
  satellites: [{
    name: 'Satellite name',
    radius: 1,
    x: 14, // относительно земли
    y: 18
  }]
}];

// здесь экземпляры планет
var planets = [];

// создаём планеты и сохраняем их в переменную planets
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  planets.push(new Planet(data[i]));
}
```

В каждый момент времени любая планета знает о своих спутниках, а спутники знают о своих планетах.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Вы очень помогли мне с системой планет, огромное спасибо, у меня появился  вопрос (извините за назойливость..) - как достучаться до имён спутников в массиве data? Как передать их в конструктор? Что-то не выходит..

Comment: по аналогии с `this.radius = data.radius;` - `this.name = data.name`. Доступ от планеты: `this.satellites[0].name`, от спутника `this.planet.name`

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли.